# Can you access a Dictionary property on an object that is in an ObservableCollection in WPF XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemscontrol

I have a View with an ItemsControl that contains a Grid.  The ItemsControl is bound to an ObservableCollection.
Each Thing has the following properties: Name (string), Value (string), LocationDictionary(tabid(string), Location)

Each Location has the following properties: Col(int), Row(int), TabId(string), IsVisible(bool)

The View is in a Tab on a WPF UserControl.

1. Is it possible in XAML to use the Dictionary on Thing to determine the Row and Column to place Thing in the ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle Setter?

   ```
   <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style>
       <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value={Binding Path=LocationsDictionary[thisTabId].Row}" />
       <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value={Binding Path=LocationsDictionary[thisTabId].Col}" />
   </Style>
   ```
2. Can the thisTabId variable be set at the view level and used in the Binding Path in the ItemsControl?

The goal here is to be able to place Things in the grid, it can only exist once, but can exist on other tabs with the same View.  I have things working for one grid with the Row and Col on Thing, but when applied to a second grid, Things end up in the same place on each grid/tab.  Thing 2 ends up in the same grid cell locaiton on each tab.

The Dictionary is one way we came up with to give a Thing multiple location attributes so it can exist on multiple tabs in different places.

Comment: `thisTabId` must be a constant unless you use a converter to get the value of the Row or Column property.

Comment: Can you invert your design so that you bind the ItemsControl to a collection of 'locators' (for want of a better word) which each contain a Row, Col, and Thing? You would then build this collection based on your real Things collection for each View (depending on its tab-id).

Comment: Let me think on that, need to figure out how to get to Thing in the ItemControl.ItemTemplate Datataemplate ContentControl Binding call.

Comment: @andrew That worked well, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do something like this in pure XAML unless `thisTabId` is a constant:

```
{Binding Path=LocationsDictionary[thisTabId].Row}
```

In other words, `thisTabId` cannot be a dynamic value that changes for each item in the `ItemsControl`. If you want to this, you could use a [multi value converter](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/wpf-multivalue-converters/) that binds to both the `LocationsDictionary` property and the `thisTabId` property and returns `LocationsDictionary[thisTabId].Row` or `LocationsDictionary[thisTabId].Column`.

Comment: thisTabId would be the same value for a single view.  With multiple tabs, and a View on each tab, the value would be different for each tabbed View.

Comment: I guess it's not a constant then.

Comment: No, the ViewModel determines that value, but it is not part of the Items list so not sure a mulit value converter will work here.

Comment: It would. It's just a matter of binding to the right property but that's another question really.